# Postfix rejecting everyhing

Tags: postfix

For some reason postfix is rejecting sending mails and I can't get why. Here are relevant lines of what I used at the beginning:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_ips,
permit_mynetworks,
permit_sasl_authenticated,
reject_unauth_destination
```

where mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8. Now, I have just upgraded postfix from 2.3.3 to 2.11.3 and the OS as well and it turns out it rejects everything even thought the config file has not changed at all. I got to the point where I changed my config to:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
#  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
#  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_ips,
#  permit_mynetworks,
#  permit_sasl_authenticated, 
#  reject_unauth_destination
permit
```

and still, postfix is rejecting with relay access denied. Why? I have got the permit at the end after all right? I will just mention that smtpd_client_restrictions are the same = permit.

Comment: and what do the postfix logs tell you?

Comment: I see this message: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from anotherserver[x.x.x.x]: 454 4.7.1 <.....@hotmail.com>: Relay access denied;  which is weird because the x.x.x.x address is in the access_ips file as x.x.x.x OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer;

After I have done the update it turned out that instead of

smtpd_recipient_restrictions

I should use:

smtpd_relay_restrictions

This has been posted here: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions

Interesting thing is that the documentation says that

```
# With Postfix 2.10 and later, the mail relay policy is
# preferably specified under smtpd_relay_restrictions.
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, ...
# With Postfix before 2.10, the relay policy can be
# specified only under smtpd_recipient_restrictions.
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, ...
```

So that means that the old command should still work whilst it does not, or perhaps, I do not fully understand it.